# Normalization images takes long

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

As mentioned below I am normalizing images array with,

> np.array(training_low_imgs)/127.5 - 1

But the problem is it takes too long. So is there a better of doing this?

```
# Training set
for img_path in train_low_path:
  if img_path.endswith('.png'):
    img = imread(os.path.join(Path().absolute(),"drive/My Drive/LOLdataset/our485/low",img_path))
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [286, 286],
                                method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    training_low_imgs.append(img)
print('Converting training imgs into numpy array')
training_low_imgs = np.array(training_low_imgs)/127.5 - 1
print('Converted training imgs into numpy array')
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this takes "too long" (whatever that means). It's just a simple division and subtraction. Most likely, the bottleneck is somewhere else, e.g. in the resizing or the fact that you are iterating over an unspecified number of images and loading them one by one.

Comment: no, I checked each line seperately. Thats what i am also wondering.

Comment: how many images do you have, and what is the time currently being taken. When you say too long, what do you mean? did you compare with some other approach and realized the current line is taking longer?

Comment: I added a timer and checked. In order to convert one image it took around 1min for me in google colab.